# Is it possible to deploy GItLab Pages without CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pages

We have a locally deployed instance of Gitlab, where at the time we cannot afford to have a GitLab Runner to run CI/CD pipelines.

Is it possible to use GitLab Pages without CI/CD? E.g. is it possible to manually prepare the HTML-content, put it in the `public` folder in the root and make it accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't want to use **GitLab shared runner which costs you and CI minutes limits**.

#### Public folder

Refer to this `gitlab-ci.yaml` for making HTML content available https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

#### Running locally without registration

Here is the known limitations: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec

Pages are directly managed by Gitlab so running locally won't affect the page's state.

#### Use your own runner and register with gitlab (Possible)

Install GitLab runner on your machine and register as a runner, instructions can be found at **Settings->CI/CD->Runners->Specific runner** Enable it for your project or group.

I use my personal machine gitlab-runner to execute CI jobs that aren't counted towards CI minutes.

Comment: The first 2 steps are misleading. Do I understand it correctly that the only way to achieve this is step 3, i.e. using your own local runner?

Comment: I am afraid I do not fully understand the answer.  Is it possible to deploy GitLab Pages without CI/CD, or is it mandatory to have CI/CD and a runner?

Comment: did any of you find an answer to the question?